# Allure reporter for Mocha doesn't report tests when root hook failed

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, allure, autotest

I try mocha with parallel mode and allure reporter, and this combination is all right in general, but has one major flaw - if any root hook in suite fails, all test just wouldn't appear in Allure report, because mocha doesn't run them, instead it skips them somehow.

In comparison, mochawesome reporter does show such tests in reports as skipped. Is there any way to make Allure also show such tests? Or, maybe, there are some other reporters for Mocha (which combine cool features from Allure and ability to show skipped tests from mochawesome) I could try?